# Identifier in Hibernate that has a dynamic prefix based on the entity attribute

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to spring and spring boot and playing around by developing a simple application. I have the following usecase as mentioned below.

I have the following class definition in my spring boot project.

```
public class Issue {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence_issue_id", strategy = "com.app.mycompany.AgileCenterServices.util.IssueIdGenerator",
                      parameters = @Parameter(name = "ProjectKey", value = "PeopleCenter" ))
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_issue_id")
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String id;

    private String projectId;
}
```

I have a IssueIdGenerator class that sets dynamic value to the id parameter in the Issue POJO class.

However, while doing so, I would like to set a prefix to the id parameter.

How should I be sending this dynamic prefix value to the IssueIdGenerator class.

The prefix value is not a fixed value and will be received as an attribute to the Issue POJO class.

Hence I would like to pass this prefix value which is present as an attribute in the Issue POJO class to the IssueIdGenerator class.

Comment: Have you tried playing with setter/getter of "id"...i.e. adding prefix at the time of calling getter/stter ...though i am not sure its going to work

Answer (score 1):

The closer you will get (Using a Generator) to your usecase is by defining a Custom Generator.

An example available in https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers is:

> Let’s create a generator that builds identifiers containing a String
>   prefix and a number:

```
public class MyGenerator    implements
 IdentifierGenerator, Configurable {

     private String prefix;

     @Override
     public Serializable generate(
       SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object obj) 
       throws HibernateException {

         String query = String.format("select %s from %s", 
             session.getEntityPersister(obj.getClass().getName(), obj)
               .getIdentifierPropertyName(),
             obj.getClass().getSimpleName());

         Stream ids = session.createQuery(query).stream();

         Long max = ids.map(o -> o.replace(prefix + "-", ""))
           .mapToLong(Long::parseLong)
           .max()
           .orElse(0L);

         return prefix + "-" + (max + 1);
     }

     @Override
     public void configure(Type type, Properties properties, 
       ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
         prefix = properties.getProperty("prefix");
     } 
 }
```

>

> In this example, we override the generate() method from the IdentifierGenerator interface and first find the highest number from
>   the existing primary keys of the form prefix-XX.
>
> Then we add 1 to the maximum number found and append the prefix
>   property to obtain the newly generated id value.
>
> Our class also implements the Configurable interface, so that we can
>   set the prefix property value in the configure() method.
>
> Next, let’s add this custom generator to an entity. For this, we can
>   use the @GenericGenerator annotation with a strategy parameter that
>   contains the full class name of our generator class:

```
@Entity 
 public class Product {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(generator = "prod-generator")
     @GenericGenerator(name = "prod-generator", 
       parameters = @Parameter(name = "prefix", value = "prod"), 
       strategy = "com.baeldung.hibernate.pojo.generator.MyGenerator")
     private String prodId;

     // ... 
 }
```

> Also, notice we’ve set the prefix parameter to “prod”.
>
> Let’s see a quick JUnit test for a clearer understanding of the id
>   values generated:

```
 @Test 
 public void whenSaveCustomGeneratedId_thenOk()
 {
     Product product = new Product();
     session.save(product);
     Product product2 = new Product();
     session.save(product2);
     assertThat(product2.getProdId()).isEqualTo("prod-2"); 
 }
```

> Here, the first value generated using the “prod” prefix was “prod-1”, followed
>   by “prod-2”.

---

Another alternative would be to use a Composite Key (JPA specification):

> A composite primary key must correspond to either a single persistent
>   field or property or to a set of such fields or properties as
>   described below. A primary key class must be defined to represent a
>   composite primary key. Composite primary keys typically arise when
>   mapping from legacy databases when the database key is comprised of
>   several columns. The EmbeddedId and and IdClass annotations are used
>   to denote composite primary keys. See sections 9.1.14 and 9.1.15.